# Making optimized melee weapons for specific style of combat with nanotechnology pt.1

Tags: weapons, nanotechnology

Let's see:

---

This question's focus:

- **Long range:**

  - **For thrusting**
  - **For slashing**
  - **For armor penetration or blunt trauma.**
  - **Medium at the previous three or two**

---

### Info

- I have patience and nanobots to build up weapons from the atomic level.
- From iron to obsidian (yes, I know, that obsidian isn't an element) I have all kinds of materials at my disposal.
- I want to keep my weapon design very clear, only putting a decoration on it, if that doesn't hinder its effectivity.
- They are specialized for one type of attack method or function (described above, in the list).

---

### Questions:

- **What tricks can I put into my weapons, with the help of nanites? *(I don't want to put anything into them, that requires energy to run, those are for another question)***
- **How would their designs look like?**

Comment: Sooo basically a duplicate of your previous question http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74207/how-to-build-the-perfect-versions-of-different-melee-weapons

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear in what you are asking. Using nanotechnology and modern materials can make any weapon more "effective" by using sharper, harder or otherwise optimized materials, and the nano forge can be programmed to make the individual weapon sized and balanced for the individual user, but a titanium katana still has most of the limitations of a steel one. in some jurisdictions you would be prevented from carrying one, and if you are fighting against a Roman Legion or someone in full plate armour from the mid 1500's, you might discover the perfect katana isn't doing you a lot of good after all......

The other factor which you have not mentioned is what exactly you are fighting against. A melee weapon for fighting against armoured knights will be far different from one you take into a bar or the improvised weapons soldiers made in WWI. Without an understanding of what the target is, and the conditions you are using them in, saying we can use nano technology to make an "optimized" weapon is rather meaningless.

Comment: `For armor penetration or blunt trauma.` Then guess what the others could be for.

Comment: Armour penetration is different from blunt trauma, and different sorts of armour need different weapons to deal with. The European long sword was effectively replaced as the melee combat weapon by the 1300's as armour technology evolved, and you can trace the evolution of swords, polearms and smashing weapons like maces and hammers along the development of armour.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not good at advanced tech... But I'll try this one:

If you have nanites then obviously cybernetics are not a problem. You need a weapon like an expandable staff. Like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruyi_Jingu_Bang)

A staff like this "Poisoned" with grey goo nanites can devastate battleships and even planets. You just need to program the nanites to not melt your soldiers.

You can also use the nanites to hack computer systems and even auto repair the staff since the nanites self replicate.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, but `(I don't want to put anything into them, that requires energy to run, those are for another question)`

Comment: You are welcome.But you can recharge the weapons with cybernetic suits and augmented troops.

Comment: I get that part, but this time, we look at the design, enchants are for another question.